# What is advantage of mulesoft over dataloader in Salesforce

Tags: dataloader.io, mulesoft

Can anyone please let me know that 
What is advantage of Mulesoft over Dataloader in Salesforce ?

Basically in which use case we should use Mulesoft

Comment: This would be a good starting point
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/mulesoft-basics

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is simple data manipulation or simple data migrations, the Data Loader suffices in these cases. As soon as you want to start integrating with other systems, migrating data between Salesforce and other platforms, etc, Mulesoft (as well as any other tool in the ecosystem) is generally better than the Data Loader. The Data Loader is a free program, but very limited in capacity.